# Create a new column evaluating empty cell

Tags: python, pandas

Starting from a df like that:

| Lev. | Qta | Text | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| .1 | 1 | Model3 | 1 |
| .2 | 2 | Gruoup1 | 1 |
| .3 | 5 | Gruoup1.1 | 4 |
| .3 | 1 | Gruoup1.2 | 1 |
| .3 | 2 | Gruoup1.3 | 1 |
| .3 | 1 | Gruoup1.4 |  |
| .3 | 1 | Gruoup1.5 |  |

I want to create a new column comparing two different columns, for do this I defined a function like this:

```
def F1(k):
    if (k['Lev'] == '.1'):
      return 'Expl1'
    elif (k['Lev'] == '.2'):
      return 'Expl2'
    elif (k['Qtà'] == k['Qty']):
        return 'OK'
    elif (k['Qtà'] > k['Qty']):
        return 'NOK'
    elif (k['Qtà'] < k['Qty']):
        return 'Less'
    elif (k['Qty'] is empty):
        return'NoMap'
    else
        Return 'Check'
df['OK/NOK'] = df.apply(F1, axis=1)
```

The function works well except when in QTY I have an empty cell. When the cell is empty i receive 'Check' answer.

This is an example of what would like to obtain:

| Lev. | Qta | Text | Qty | OK/NOK. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| .1 | 1 | Model3 | 1 | Expl1 |
| .2 | 2 | Gruoup1 | 1 | Expl2. |
| .3 | 5 | Gruoup1.1 | 4 | Less. |
| .3 | 1 | Gruoup1.2 | 1 | OK. |
| .3 | 2 | Gruoup1.3 | 1 | NOK. |
| .3 | 1 | Gruoup1.4 |  | NoMap. |
| .3 | 1 | Gruoup1.5 |  | NoMap. |

Comment: make elif (k['Qty'] is empty) condition as a third condition after (k['Lev'] == '.2', before comparing with Qty IF condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a vectorial approach.

A possibility is to use `numpy.select` with all individual conditions.

```
import numpy as np

df['OK/NOK'] = np.select([df['Lev'] == '.1', df['Lev'] == '.2', ...],
                         ['Expl1', 'Expl2', ...],
                         'Check')
```

Another one would be to use a pandas approach:

```
import numpy as np

r1 = df['Lev'].map({'.1': 'Expl1', '.2': 'Expl2'})
r2 = np.sign(df['Qta']-df['Qty']).map({1: 'NOK', 0: 'OK', -1: 'LESS'})
r3 = pd.isna(df['Qty']).map({True: 'NoMap', False: 'Check'})

df['OK/NOK'] = r1.fillna(r2).fillna(r3)
```

output:

```
  Lev  Qta       Text  Qty OK/NOK
0  .1    1     Model3  1.0  Expl1
1  .2    2    Gruoup1  1.0  Expl2
2  .3    5  Gruoup1.1  4.0    NOK
3  .3    1  Gruoup1.2  1.0     OK
4  .3    2  Gruoup1.3  1.0    NOK
5  .3    1  Gruoup1.4  NaN  NoMap
6  .3    1  Gruoup1.5  NaN  NoMap
```